# sun.font.FontDesignMetrics compile error in JDK 7

Tags: java, java-7

Following code compiles well with JDK5 but for JDK7 it throws a compile error saying

> "sun.font.FontDesignMetrics" is private

```
FontUIResource fontUiResource = (FontUIResource) MyUI.get("MainTitle");
if (fontUiResource != null) {
FontDesignMetrics fontMetrics = new FontDesignMetrics(fontUiResource);
```

I'm using Intellij 12, just in case if this is information related to the problem.

Comment: Why are you using any of the `sun.*` classes to begin with?  They're not public API, not documented, and subject to breakage between versions.

Comment: I've not explicitly added them to my classpath, they are there by default. The code is same, but gives error when I change the JDK version.

Comment: Yes, they are indeed there.  The question is, for what purpose are you using them?  They're not part of the public API so their signature can change and breakage can occur between versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the constructors were made private in jdk6. The JavaDoc of the constructor [says](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/font/FontDesignMetrics.java#328): "Its private to enable caching - call getMetrics() instead". Such a change is of course always one of the risks when using a private unsupported API.

Answer (score 0):

```
Graphics graphics = image.getGraphics();
FontMetrics metrics = graphics.getFontMetrics(font);
```

Try this one.